# Background image not applying to one div on Chrome for Mac

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, d3.js

I have a website hosted on GitHub pages here: https://justinjiaxinghu.github.io/tsm-analysis/

On windows Chrome the bottom div with the filtering buttons is integrated nicely where it's background is the dark grey background as set in the wrapper div. However on Mac Chrome it shows that the buttons are part of a pure white div where the background image is not applying. Any reasons as to why this is happening?

Comment: I'm on a Mac so I can't tell what it looks like on windows but maybe set #home-wrapper `height: 100%;` and `min-height: 100vh;` On my screen, 120vh isn't enough to cover the entire document height so it scrolls the background up too high.

Comment: @Will that seems to have fixed it. Can you explain to me what's going on with the code you suggested I add? I'm new to front end / web dev so it would be great if you could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Element Height vs Viewer Height**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

> The height CSS property specifies the height of an element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

> Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

> The min-height CSS property sets the minimum height of an element. It prevents the used value of the height property from becoming smaller than the value specified for min-height.

We have a moderately complicated combination of height values.

The style was:

```
#home-wrapper {
background-image: ...
height: 120vh
}
```

Which told the browser to make the element 120% of the height of the browser window. This probably worked some or most of the time, but it depends on the size of the browser window. The content *inside* the wrapper could (and in some cases would) overflow. That is, after the chart is laid out, it is longer than the wrapper. So it sticks out the bottom. Since the background was specified on the wrapper, the part that poked out the bottom was drawn over the default background color (white).

Changing it to this:

```
#home-wrapper {
background-image: ...
height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Does a couple of things. First, the wrapper is now 100% height, so it stretches around all of the content. We could call it good and leave it there, BUT what happens if there is a really tall browser, taller than the wrapper? Then we would have some white background peeking out at the bottom again. This time, instead of the content being taller than the viewer, the viewer would be taller than the content.

So, we use `min-height`. This says, hey at a `minimum` the height should be `100vh`. That way, if the content is SHORTER than the viewer, make the wrapper stretch to fill the entire viewer.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks Will. I implemented the suggested changes and actually now the right side of the chart spills over into white space. I tried setting min-width to 100vw and width to 100% but that still leaves a small white portion